# how to define a function in Python 3 that sort an array and return the number that exists only once rather than twice

Tags: python, python-3.x

in this code I want to do the following
1- sort the array
2- Iterate over it to find an element that exists only once while every other element exist twice. e,g [2,1,3,2,3], answer is 1
3- In iteration I do the following
 ->If reached last element , then last element is the wanted
 ->If an element i is not equal to element i+1, then element i is the wanted
4- at the end return -1 if not found

this is my code, please help me, I am new in Python

```
class Main:
    def singleNumber(self, nums: List[int]) -> int:
        sorted(nums)
        l =len(nums)
        while i<l:
            if i+1==l:
                re=nums(i)
            if nums(i)!=nums(i+1):
                re=nums(i)
            else:
                i+=1
            re=-1
        return re
```

Comment: `sorted` returns a new list

Comment: [2,1,3,2,3], shoudl return [1] ?

Comment: ``sorted(nums)`` creates a new list; use ``nums.sort()`` or ``nums = sorted(nums)`` instead. The ``while i<l:`` loop will not terminate because of incorrectly incrementing ``i``; use ``for i in range(l)`` instead. ``nums(i)`` *calls* ``nums`` – use ``nums[i]`` to index it. ``re=-1`` is run unconditionally, overwriting every result found – use a new ``list`` to hold results and ``.append`` them when found.

Comment: Start [here](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html). And for the record, Python is not Java - you don't have to use classes where all you need is a plain function.

Answer (score 1):

you can use `collections.Counter` with the built-in function `sorted`:

```
from collections import Counter
nums = [2,1,3,2,3]


sorted(k for k, v in Counter(nums).items() if v == 1)
```

output:

```
[1]
```